# Read a PDF Line by Line - iTextSharp

Tags: vb.net, itext

I'm not sure what is wrong with my code. It reads the PDF file, and grabs all the text, but every item is combined together into one string with no separator of any kind.

Sample:

"Houses: 2

Bedrooms: 3

Bathsroom 4"

will get read as "Houses: 2Bedrooms: 3Bathsroom 4"

I've searched through all of the examples to no avail. I've also tried LocationTextExtractionStrategy to no avail. I've tried using the .split method and no help.

```
Public Shared Function ParseAllPdfText(ByVal filepath As String) 
    Dim sbtxt, currenttext As String

    sbtxt = ""
    Try

        Using reader As New PdfReader(filepath)

            For intPages As Integer = 1 To reader.NumberOfPages

                currenttext = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, intPages, New LocationTextExtractionStrategy())
                currenttext = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ASCIIEncoding.Convert(Encoding.[Default], Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.[Default].GetBytes(currenttext)))
                sbtxt = sbtxt & currenttext & vbcrlf

            Next

        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(" There was an error extracting text from the file: " & ex.Message, vbInformation, "Error Extracting Text")

    End Try
    Return sbtxt
```

Comment: Can you share the pdf in question? Furthermore, what do you intend to achieve with that `Encoding` juggling line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, this was an oversight on my part. I realized the lines are separated by Chr(10). Chr(10) does not create a new line in textboxes, which is where I was outputting my string. It DOES however create a new line in MsgBox. So if anyone else runs into this problem, chr(10) is the separator. :-)